# Datamapper - before :destroy callback being called twice?

Tags: ruby-datamapper

For some reason, when I call destroy on an instance of one of my DataMapper models, the "before :destroy" callback is being executed twice, leading to errors. The model in question has a belongs_to association with another model, which has a :destroy constraint on the parent side. Can anyone see why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see some minimal example code to give you some more specific advice.

Since I found this post while looking for ways to call `self.save` inside a `before :save` callback, one of many possible explanations is that you have a `before :destroy` callback that is calling `self.destroy`...